# Can you prepopulate an image field with an existing image?

Tags: templates

It seems like you can do this via the Default Value item in the field properties but when I add the path to the image I want, and then create an item with that template, it doesn't show that image.  If I click Browse it puts me in the source folder I specify, which has that default, but is there a way to prepulate the image into the item without having to go in and select it manually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what Standard Values are for. You can set the value of the field on the `__Standard Values` item underneath the template of the item you're creating (or a base template, if you prefer):

[image]

If the `__Standard Values` item does not exist under your template, you can add it:

1. Select on your template in the Content Editor
2. Ensure the **Builder** content tab is selected
3. In the **Builder Options** ribbon tab, click the **Standard values** button

There's also another question/answer with [more information on the difference between Default Values and Standard Values](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7899/what-is-the-difference-between-default-value-of-a-template-and-its-standard-val).

Answer (score 0):

If you provide the raw value in the default field then on creating an item it will show the image. For example - Set Default field value as

[image]